# OpenLayers map wraps. Repeated map areas give invalid coordinates

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I'm using OpenLayers to display a world map on my site. The map wraps to either side, and, in the repeated sections, the coordinates are bonkers.

[image: Wrapping world map]

The pins on the map can be moved. If we move them over to a repeated section, instead of getting the actual coordinates of that spot on the globe, we get an invalid coordinate set which makes that pin disappear from the map altogether.

Here's the code I'm using for the map:

```
    this.maps.vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      });

    this.maps.vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: self.maps.vectorSource
      });

      this.maps.rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({wrapDateLine: false})
      });

      this.maps.map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({mouseWheelZoom:false}),
        layers: [self.maps.rasterLayer, self.maps.vectorLayer],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([-98.583333, 37.833333], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

You can see I've tried setting the `wrapDateLine` option to `false`, but this doesn't have any effect best I can tell.

I'd like to solve this either by preventing the map from repeating or by ensuring the repeating sections report proper coordinates. At this point, I don't much care which. Any ideas how I can achieve one of these two results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anthony got me going in the right direction with his answer. We were using OL 3.1.1 which doesn't support `wrapX`. I updated to 3.2.0 and was able to turn off wrapping. However, this created a both a UX problem (the map now ends on either side and the user needs to manually move back to the other side) and a UI problem (our wide area for map display is now mostly empty).

I tried moving up to the latest version (3.7.0) which, I noticed, began wrapping the vector layer. (Vector wrapping was lost in the move to OL 3 but was restored later.) This allowed me to turn my map wrapping back on, and the pins are drawn on each repeat of the map. It also now reports the correct coordinates even on the repeated maps.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of OpenLayers, you may need to use different options to disable the horizonal repeat.  Try adding the following options to your OSM source:

```
wrapX: false,
noWrap: true
```

I've made a jsFiddle with a slightly modified version of your code to illustrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/fg1oxpu0/

Comment: This worked, but I had to update to OpenLayers 3.2 in order to make it work. I found another solution to my problem of bogus coordinates that allowed me to continue wrapping my map.